# Why does google prefer not to use hyphen? [Hyphen vs No Hyphen]

Tags: hyphenation

One of the things that keeps bothering me while using Google's products such as Google Docs, Google Slides, or search engine is the red line under words that include hyphen **(e.g. co-operate, broken-hearted...etc).**

---

I do know the usage of hyphen and I do prefer to use it for the purpose of clarification but I can't figure out why google always keeps suggesting to remove it **(i.e. cooperate, brokenhearted...etc).**

- Does it have anything to do with rhetoric?
- Did the hyphen become non-standard?
- Did it become old-fashioned?

[image: No-hyphen suggestion]

Comment: Btw, *cooperate* is not longer hyphenated, not at least in contemporary American writing, while broken-hearted ironically is.

Comment: I once read an article about this point; thus I suspected it has something to do with contemporary English and the omitting of hyphen.

Comment: It could be worse. Be glad that Google doesn't follow the *New York Times* writing style, they always add the diacritic to coöperate and naïve.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about the English language but about a product.

Answer (score 1):

Who says Google prefers not to use the hyphen?

In Google Search, the search string format has some features, including a special meaning for the hyphen character.  When you enter a hyphenated pair or group of words, Google searches for the exact pattern, with or without a hyphen.

When words are entered unhyphenated, Google searches for the words, not the phrase.

Of course, the hyphen in hyphenated words (not phrases but say prefixed words) is a different matter. You can enter **"co-operate" -cooperate** with the quotation marks around the hyphenated word. (The hyphen when placed in front of the word tells Google to **exclude** "cooperate", it's actually the minus sign in this case.) Just try all combinations and see the behavior of the algorithm.

Here are a few [tricks](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en) with Google Search; Good Luck.

Comment: OP doesn't seem to be talking about Google search; rather about Google products (Docs and Slides).

Comment: It's no mystery how Google search suggestions work: the suggestions are [based off previous searches](https://searchengineland.com/how-google-instant-autocomplete-suggestions-work-62592) (and vary based off region too). However, this doesn't explain why the spell checker used in the Google suite of apps (Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, etc.) doesn't have these hyphenated forms in its dictionary. Also, the focus on Google is a little misplaced—"co-operate" isn't in my dictionary (NOAD) with a hyphen either.

Comment: Type in search engine "co-operate," Google suggests "Do you mean cooperate?"
Type in Google Dictionary "co-operate," Google Dictionary replies with no hyphen. 
Not sure why Google emphasize not to use hyphen in all of its products and I do already know that I can search for the hyphenated words but I'm seeking the reason why Google prefers not.

Comment: @Laurel I've checked Cambridge and Oxford English Dictionaries- both of them have hyphen for words like "broken-hearted" unlike Google.

Comment: @ArchCapital Keep checking dictionaries and you'll find one that gives you both "brokenhearted" and "cooperate" (such as Merriam Webster) :P

Comment: The gist of my answer above is that Google doesn't want to screw up the search process with a "hyphen," a "concatenator," and a "minus sign" sharing one token. I don't think of it as a case of an idiosyncrasy or a love lost.

Comment: @Laurel I always believed *broken-hearted* is (was) necessarily hyphenated because we want to emphasize both word. "Broken" -- omg! "heart" -- of all things! But we are getting lazier by the day: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=broken-hearted%2C+brokenhearted&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbroken%20-%20hearted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbrokenhearted%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Laurel And "heart(-)broken" https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heart-broken%2Cheartbroken&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheart%20-%20broken%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheartbroken%3B%2Cc0